# How to initialise a final variable that requires complex computation?

Tags: java, variables, methods, constructor, final

I'm a beginner at Java. I was wondering, what to do in situations where a variable requires complex computation before being initialised, but once initialised, it will *not* change. I wanted to make the variable final, but instead of initialising it in constructor, I would rather initialise it in a method so this method can be reused later. Is there any way to achieve this?

In addition to all the requirements above, what happen if I want to compute the value of this variable only when I need it (because its computationally expensive to calculate it). What should I do in situations like this?

Comment: you can always write a method that computes the value for the final variable and invoke the method in constructor to assign the return value to final variable. Why not?

Comment: For your second question, you pass a boolean to the constructor of the object , `shouldInitializeFinalVariable` and depending on that invoke the expensive method, otherwise default to parameter less constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the memoize supplier from [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki):

```
Supplier<T> something = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<T>() {
    // heavy computation
    return result.
});

something.get();
something.get(); // second call will return the memoized object.
```

Comment: I wonder how many developers other than Google's own use Guava in daily development?

Comment: @svasa If you develop for a day without using Guava, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @shmosel I don't agree. It is absolutely possible to write neat, efficient, maintanable, highly available code without Guava. On the other hand I know Guava is a nice library no doubt about it, do all orgs allow their developers to use it and ship products with Guava dependency ?

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, you can't make a variable final in just any given moment.** If a variable is `final` it can (and must) be initialized in the constructor.

You could also do this (credit to npinti for following code):

```
private boolean isMutable;
private String someString;

public void setMutable(boolean value)
{
    this.isMutable = value;
}

public void setSomeString(String value)
{
    if (this.isMutable)
    {
        this.someString = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look likes you need Lazy initialization. It is a performance optimization to use use when a result is considered to be expensive for some reason. The objectives is to 
delay an expensive computation until it is necessary and 
store the result of that expensive computation such that the computation do not need to repeat again.

Following is an example:

```
public final class Foo {
    private Data data = null; 

    private Data expensiveComputation() {
        if(data == null) { // first call to this method
            Data data = new Data();
            // complex computation
            // store the result to data
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see `data` is initialized only when it is needed.

Be careful that there will be problem if your code work in a multi-thread environment. It is because multiple threads can call the method at the same time. To prevent this we can use a `synchronized` keyword:

```
public final class Foo {
    private volatile Data data = null; 

    private Data expensiveComputation() {
        if(data == null) { // first call to this method
            synchronized(Foo.class) {
                if(data == null) {
                    Data data = new Data();
                    // complex computation
                    // store the result to data
                }
            }
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

The `synchronized` keyword only allow one thread can enter and initialize `data`.

Comment: The last example doesn't work with multiple threads unless data is made volatile.